# Orthogonal Vectors

Tags: math

Given a vector V of size N, Find if there exists another vector A (of size N) such that A.V = 0 where . represents the Dot product or Inner Product ie a1*v1 + a2*v2 + a3 * v3 + ... an*vn = 0, and A >0 ie all ai are non-negative integers and all ais cannot be 0 at the same time(trivial case).
Suggest an algorithm to generate a YES of NO.

Comment: Uh oh, do you have an assignment due soon?

Comment: At least...did you try something on your own? We don't like doing other peoples work.

Comment: This site frowns very heavily on posting what look like homework assignments quoted verbatim, without any sign of effort on the original poster's part. If this is homework, please tag it as such, and make some effort to ask a **QUESTION**. Your post includes no questions, just statements.

Comment: Not a homework question. Its actually a simplification of a problem I encountered in a programming contest.

Comment: This also isn't really a vector problem, so your title is misleading.  Anybody familiar with vector analysis will consider finding an orthogonal vector trivial, and your requirement for integer components to be weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider first the case when at least one of v<sub>i</sub> = 0. Then it is easy for you to show that the answer is YES. Now move on to the cases where all the v<sub>i</sub> ≠ 0. Now break this into two more subcases.

1. All the v<sub>i</sub> have the same sign.
2. At least one pair, say v<sub>i</sub> and v<sub>j</sub>, i ≠ j , have different signs.

You should be able to complete the assignment from this breakdown.

Comment: The problem comes when ai have to be integers. Let v = { 2, -7 } say, then no solution exists. The answer is a NO.

Comment: @shreedhar:  How about {7, 2}?  7*2 + 2*(-7) is 0.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to jump out on a limb here based on some intuition. Try the set of vectors A where a1..an are 0 or 1. So for size N you will have 2**N vectors in this set. Take the dot product V.A for each of these. If there are at least one positive and at least one negative dot product, then there exists one vector in that quadrant/octant/X-ant where the dot product is zero, otherwise not.

The dot product will interpolate as you interpolate between vectors, so if there is a positive one and a negative one, then some linear combination of those will have a dot product that is zero.

The intuition part is that this test is sufficient - i.e. the "otherwise not" part.

Edit: This ends up being equivalent to "if there is at least one positive component of V AND one negative component, then yes. Otherwise no."